# npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn git

Tags: truffle, react, npm, truffle-box

I use the command `npx truffle unbox react` to develop a dapp but I get these errors below in my console. Can anybody help me? I really don't know how can I solve them.
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems you do not have git installed or it is not configured to execute from cmd properly.

Comment: I've set my git to my environment variables and then I solve this error. Oh yeah!

Comment: @Ismael still thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I already install git in my computer. However, I forget to set it to environment variables. After I set it, the error disappeared and unboxed react successfully. 
**The solution of this error is to set git to environment variables.**

Comment: "to set git to environment variables" is not a solution. Its not even a proper instruction. Which environment variable did you set and which value did you set it to?